# Security implications of generating salts immediately vs. when needed

Tags: security, encryption, hash, passwords, salt

Say I have a database of users (customers).  Some of these customers have logged in through a portal, some of them have not and only exist in the database to facilitate customer management by an administrator.  At a later date, customers may decide to begin using the portal, at which point they'll need to be provided a password.

Assuming the randomization method is reasonably secure, are there any security implications related to the **timing** of the salt generation?

ie.: is it better, worse, or irrelevant to be salting all accounts as early as possible vs. salting only at the time a password is created?

Comment: The question is lacking how the salt will be used and how the passwords are handled, a language and a platform (computer/device).

Comment: Note: For security verification passwords need to be saved in such a manner that they are **not recoverable**. In the case of a user later needing access the user will need to enter a new password.

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Cryptography Stack Exchange](http://crypto.stackexchange.com/) or [Information Security Stack Exchange](http://security.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Answer (score -1):

The main idea behind the salts, is to offer protection against rainbow tables, which are databases containing pre-hashed passwords. Having each password salted using a different salt allows you to minimize this risk, since now (in theory) there should be no rainbow table containing your password.

As long as you're using a cryptographically secure pseudo-random number generator (CSPRNG) to generate your salts, there should not be a problem with salting your passwords as early as possible (and it'll be even better if you use the salting mechanism already included in most modern implementations). After all, you only care about always producing a different hash. And salts are not even secret values, if your database got compromised, the attacker will already have the hashed password and the salt (they're usually stored like salt$base64HashedPassword, or they just have a column for the salt), and salts are not like the IVs in cipher block chaining (CBC) where an attacker can take advantage of a predictable IV. Here you only care about always producing a different hash, so as long as you do it, everything should be ok.

**Edit:** Now I'm curious about something. You're talking about salting the password someday in the future... does that mean that you're storing it as plaintext or in a recoverable way before salting it? Because now that'll be a bad practice. You need to salt it as soon as you get it, since you should not know anything about user's passwords.

Comment: Just using a hash function is not sufficient and just adding a salt does little to improve the security. Instead iterate over an HMAC with a random salt for about a 100ms duration and save the salt with the hash. Use a function such as `PBKDF2`, `Rfc2898DeriveBytes`, `password_hash`, `Bcrypt` or similar functions. The point is to make the attacker spend a lot of time finding passwords by brute force.

Comment: Regarding your last question, no, passwords are never stored as plain text.  These are customer records that are inaccessible by the customer themselves, until they've verified their identity.

Comment: @zaph He's just asking if there's any problem with salting right away, or someday in the future, not about particular algorithms. I'm obviously assuming that he's using a good algorithm for this, and not just "MD5 with a salt". Downvoting just because I answered what was asked, is like if I downvoted you because you never mentioned how to get a good random salt (hey, someone could be using Math.Random with the current date timestamp as a seed to create his salts, and he'll never know).

Comment: The answer addresses passwords and salting and salting minimally helps security. Proper password hashing directly affects the users so it is important to provide good guidance. The last thing we need is more poor security that directly affects the users.

Comment: And @RecoveringNerdaholic As long as you're doing it right, there should be no problem with generating your salt in the moment that the account was created or someday in the future (I just saw that you're technically use the "Password" field, as an "IsActive" field, and if there's no password, then he's nos active on that platform).

Comment: Here's is the thing: An answer can also guide the OP and others who read the answer to a more seciure solution. How great is that!

Comment: @zaph Then do us all a favor and create an answer covering absolutely everything. You know, proper algorithms to handle this problem, dos and don'ts, how to generate a proper salt to be used with HMAC, the best number of iterations that he needs to use with PBKDF2 or the work factor to be used with BCrypt (hey, he could be using a really low number of iterations just to keep things fast). Again, he's just asking if the timing is a problem, Is it a problem? No, and we need to assume that he's doing the rest of the stuff right, unless he says something that makes us think the opposite.

Comment: @zaph I get your point, you want to make sure that anyone reading this will get the right idea, but again, someone searching a question about "the timing problem" only cares about that, and someone searching for a "proper hashing function for password storage" will search for that. It's not like I'm expicitly saying "Hey, yeah, pick any hashing algorithm like MD5 or SHA128 and add a salt". But still, I think that this discussion in the comments section will be useful for anyone else reading this in the future.

Comment: Interesting I often see a really good answer goes wrong because of additional information, "Snatching defeat from the jaws of success."

Comment: "salts are not like the IVs in cipher block chaining (CBC) where an attacker can take advantage of a predictable IV": what? predictability makes no difference, they just need to be different and we assume that random IVs will be different. It is only there so that two identical messages with different IVs will be different from each other. See previous comment. <g>

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/148710/discussion-between-esteban-cervantes-and-zaph).